# Javascript / Adjusting colors

Tags: javascript, amcharts

We are using this [chart](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/3d-pie-chart/). I see there is no property available to customize the colors of the pie chart.

- Is there a way to customize the colors ?
- Also how can we enable legend for this (if we could display legend in the bottom of the graph, it could be great. i.e like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCUiZ.png) )? and display only percentage on the graph?
- To make the graph exploded, i see we need to use ["pulled": true] in the dataProvider. Instead of providing it inside the dataProvider, is there a way to provide somewhere outside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to customize colors

1) Use the [`colorField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#colorField) and define the colors directly for individual slices.

2) Set your own theme by modifying the [`colors`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#colors) array or create your own [theme](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/working-with-themes/).

Legends are enabled by setting an empty legend object in the chart config. You can find further configuration properties [in the documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend). You can even change the value label to use percentages by modifying the [`valueText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#valueText) property. There's also an example of a pie chart [with the legend set up](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/pie-chart-with-legend/) and a [completely custom legend](http://www.amcharts.com/tips/fully-functional-custom-legend-pie-chart/).

If you want to change the pie slices labels, change the [`labelText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#labelText).

As for your last question, no - it's  using [`pulledField`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#pulledField) to specify which slices are pulled out in your data. There isn't a setting to explode the entire chart without it.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you here again. I have already accepted the answer. However, my question is related to this thread. So trying to post it here as a comment. Is there a way to round the pie chart (amchart) edges ? like the image seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32077817/highcharts-3d-pie-chart-rounding-the-edges).

Comment: No, there isn't.